# Use of cotangent with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, math

The library numpy does not contain a cotangent function, I'd like to use cotangent in my program.

Googling this yields no usable results.

Many thanks.

Comment: `cot(a) == 1 / tan(a)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NumPy, you can compute the cotangent of an angle given in radians using the np.tan() function and then taking its reciprocal. There's no direct np.cot() function, but you can easily compute cotangent as follows:

```
import numpy as np

# Your angle in radians
angle_radians = 3

# Compute the cotangent
cotangent = 1 / np.tan(angle_radians)

print(cotangent)
```

Remember to input the angle in radians, as the np.tan() function expects radians.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cot%283+radians%29&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22radians%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Unit%22%7D

Comment: I did some tests on speed and precision, seeing if my two solutions were different. and as it stands, 1/tan is the best in both speed and precision, thank you for the answer ^u^

Answer (score 2):

Cotangent can be derived like so:

```
def cotan(x):
    return -numpy.tan(x + numpy.pi/2)
```

or

```
def cotan(x):
    return numpy.cos(x)/numpy.sin(x)
```

My guess is the first methiod would be faster, however I have not tested their speed.

I don't know why exactly python doesn't have this function defined

Answer (score 0):

```
from numpy import *

def cotangent(number: float) -> float:
    cotangent: float = 1 / tan(number)
    return cotangent

if __name__ == "__main__":
   result: float = cotangent(float(input("enter number")))
   print(f"{result}")
```

I think this will do.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).